# identity and inverse elements from a group

Tags: discrete-mathematics

so, i have this Question:

based on a set $\mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}$ provided by this expression:

$(a,b)*(c,d) = (ac,bd)$

find the identity element and the inverse element.

finding the identity element i did:

$(a,b)*(c,d) = (a,b)$
$(c,d) = (a,b)/(a,b) = 1$

Finding the inverse element:

$(a,b)*(c,d) = 1$

$(c,d) = 1/(a,b)$

Its correct?}

Comment: I get the feeling that this is a part of a question. Can you please write down the whole question. What is your group?

Comment: I think it's product of two group like $G\times H$. You should express the form of $1$.

Comment: i wrote the entire question.

Comment: @JinyongGo how it should be? and, the logic is correct?

Comment: @MatheusSilva It doesn't have inverse in this group. Clearly $\Bbb Z$ is not a group under multiplication.

Comment: @JinyongGo '-', so, how can i show there is not an inverse element? and its not a group

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(c,d)\in \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is identity.

Then, for all $(a,b)\in \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$, $$(a,b)*(c,d)=(c,d)*(a,b)=(a,b)$$ which means $ac=ca=a, bd=db=b$

You know what $c, d$ is.

Also, for mutiplicative inverse, you can just consider $(0,0)$. Does it have inverse?

Comment: so, i understand that (C,D) is (1,1) correct? is the only way to achieve (a,b).

ok, and considering (0,0) as inverse, multipling by (a,b) (or whatever) it will not exist(will be 0,0) correct? so, dont have an inverse.

Comment: @MatheusSilva Yeah, that's right.

Comment: i was thinking better, why i can just consider (0,0) as the inverse?

Comment: So, i was thiking better, the inverse is 1/(a,b) = (1/a, 1/b).
(a,b)*(1/a, 1/b) = 1 -> a*1/a = 1 | b*1/b = 1 -> (1,1). (a,b)*(j,k) = (1,1) where (j,k) is any inverse, so its the only way to achieve (1,1).